# Problem trying to fill vertical space in page

Tags: angular, flexbox

I'm trying to fill vertically all the space in a page using @angular/flex-layout.

I'm using fxFill and fxFlex to build the layout. It seems to be ok when I place the objects horzontally, but I can't find a way for filling the page vertically. Here is my simplest version.

Following cod fills correctly all orizontal sapce.

```
<div fxFill>
    <label >
        First item
    </label>
    <label fxFlex>
        Second item
    </label>
    <label >
        Third item
    </label>
</div>
```

But following codo does not fill all the space vertically:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxFill>
    <label >
        First item
    </label>
    <label fxFlex>
        Second item
    </label>
    <label >
        Third item
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the height of html and body to 100% for it to take effect. Since the directive applies a `width: 100%; height: 100%` style to the container, you will have a page which is 200% the height of the viewport.

Here is an example with a 300 by 300 containing div for each layout example:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}

<div class="container">
  <div fxFill>
    <label>
        First item
    </label>
    <label fxFlex>
        Second item
    </label>
    <label >
        Third item
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div fxLayout="column" fxFill>
    <label >
        First item
    </label>
    <label fxFlex>
        Second item
    </label>
    <label>
        Third item
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-fill-space)

Comment: OMG! I've been adding   style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"  everywhere in my project but the <HTML> element. Thank you very much!!!!